# Is there a better way to load View Controllers from a table view?

Tags: objective-c, ios

This might be a very basic question, but I could not find the answer yet.
I have a UITableView that acts as a menu for my app. Each row on the table view, when selected, opens a different subclass of UIViewController.

At the moment my code works the same way used in the UICatlog example from Apple.
In the main view controller (the table view), each menu item is described in a dictionary in an array (menuList). Each dictionary contains an instance of the UIViewController subclass for that screen and other data about the menu item. When the user selects a row, the didSelectRow atIndexPath kicks in and calls the appropriate view controller, stored in the dictionary at that indexPath.row of the menuList array.

It seems to be very wasteful to alloc and init every single view controller when the table view first loads.

My question is: Is there a better way than the one demonstrated in UICatalog to alloc/init my view controller sublasses only when the associated row is tapped? 
(I know I can use a complex if..else structure in the didSelectRow, but this results in an extremely long didSelectRow method and breaks encapsulation. I wonder if there is a cleaner way to do this, allocing and initing the appropriate view controller based on data from the dictionaries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I could not find a better way to do this, the memory signature of each allocated View Controller is only 288 bytes. Since the solution suggested by apple is a lot more elegant and scalable then using a switch case statement, I left it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

user1349768 try to use Storyboard, but this feature only works in iOs 4 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion ... put some reference to each view controller into NSArray and then initiate and segue to them when the row gets tapped on (and just get the reference from objectAtIndex:).

Comment: Thank you but I'm not using a storyboard. My app is built similarly to the UICatalog sample code.

Comment: It should be possible the same way without storyboard and seque programatically or just push the subviews (don't know exact way put definitely possible).

Comment: Offcourse I'm pushing the subviews, thats not the problem (see UICatalog sample code). The problem is how to cleanly alloc/init the correct view controller subclass only when its needed, without creating a long and messy didSelectRow method.

Comment: I would alloc/init them in TableViewController viewDidLoad into NSArray and then in didSelectRow just push the view with given index.

Comment: Thats what the code already does... I'm trying to find a more efficient way. I don't want to alloc/init every single screen in the app the moment the tableview loads, only the one the user requested.

Comment: You may have properties and lazily instantiate them (messy but efficient)